# Why host third party libs instead of relying on CDN, Nuget, GitHub?

Tags: package-manager, github

I'm struggling with some enterprise security guidelines requiring 3rd party libs to be hosted internally. The immediate concern is over our build server connecting to GitHub for package resolution, but we've been hitting NuGet for years and were blissfully pursuing CDN hosts for our in-flight production apps.

What security does self-hosting provide if I already trust the package author & contents?

Answer (score 3):

> What security does self-hosting provide if I already trust the package author & contents?

Including content from a third party system outside of your control does not only mean that you need to trust the authors of the content to not willingly add malicious content but that you also need to trust them to keep their systems available and secure. In other words: including content from a third party host makes your vulnerable against DOS attacks to this hosts (i.e. harm availability) and also compromise of the third party system which can impact your own security.

Comment: That all still sounds like "availability" not necessarily "security". If I reference a lib from Google's or GitHub's CDN, and in the unlikely event that they get DOS'ed (meaning they haven't prevented the attack), I may lose my lib reference. So a backup source will help me stay up, but doesn't seem any more secure.

Comment: @ajamrozek:  If you usually just download the unsigned libs from github anyway then it is mainly a availability problem. If you instead get the libs directly from the developers and maybe also signed then using github or similar instead also adds yet another system which might be compromised.

Comment: Availability is security. Otherwise we'd sink every computer to the Marianas Trench in a welded-shut safe and call it secure.

Comment: Ignoring the availability issue with in-flight product for a moment; what's the security issue with resolving packages from an internet source at build time?

Comment: @ajamrozek: see my last comment (23 hours ago) about this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: I saw your comment. I didn't see an answer in there. I'm sure your German is better than mine, but your English broke down a little. 

If I'm using a signed, trusted package hosted on a CDN, backed up by a different redundant source, how does that affect my security posture?

Comment: @ajamrozek: **If** you are using a package signed by the author then this iis mainly an availability problem as I said. **If not** then this can be a security problem. So do you use a signed package by the author or not? Your question does not provide this information.

Comment: My question has to do with hosting. Weather I have a signed/trusted package or not, *hosting* the package internally provides no obvious security benefit to me.

Comment: @ajamrozek: If the package is not signed then you will not realize if somebody has tampered with it. In this case each additional party and each additional system outside of your control which is involved in the distribution (i.e. third party hosting) means additional risk of tampering.

Comment: Ah, there's a keen takeaway for security instead of availability.

Answer (score 1):

Self-hosting packages instead of leveraging NuGet or a CDN (say, for js libraries) would in theory, provide some benefits:

- Ideally, you have full control of the respository such that you know exactly the source of the files, the security posture of the repository and can ensure that the packages haven't been modified illicitly via compromise of that third party - while you're happily taking them as a dependency in your project. You also control all administrative access and publishing rights to vetted individuals.
  (That being said, NuGet has recognized the need for clients to ensure more trust in the authenticity of a package, and has a blog post outlining the details of their plans in this blog post: https://blog.nuget.org/20170914/NuGet-Package-Signing.html)
- Exacting engineering teams can essentially "whitelist" and restrict the allowed packages that you can take as a dependency in your project, after they've been successfully vetted through some security rigor and assurance process. For example, I can restrict the versions of any given package to ones that had resolved a known public vulnerability.  Also, whitelisting known-good packages is more likely to prevent a typo in the dependency configuration from opening me up to pulling a package with malicious contents, as described by recent "typosquatting" concerns: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/08/02/typosquatting_npm/

Comment: I could whitelist packages & versions from my packages config regardless of source, no?